# Python Iterating through Directories and Renaming

Tags: python, iteration, rename

I am trying to iterate through a list of subdirectories and then opening the files within that subdirectory and renaming the files to lowercase. Here is my code:

```
for root, subdirs, pics in os.walk(rootdir):
  for pic in pics:
    if pic.endswith('.jpg'):
        picpath = os.path.join(pic)
        #print pic
        print picpath
        #os.rename(pic, pic.replace(" ", "-").lower())
        os.rename(picpath, picpath.replace(" ", "-").lower())
```

I then get:

> *Traceback (most recent call last): File "imageresizing-renamefiles.py", line 19, in 
>   os.rename(picpath, picpath.replace(" ", "-").lower()) OSError: [Errno
>   2] No such file or directory*

My file structure is a root directory where the code runs from and within that folder are the following 
`folder1` with `Image1jpg` and `Image2jpg`, `folder2` with `Image3jpg` and `Image4jpg` and so on. I want to iterate through each to rename the files (not the folders) to lower case names.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: You probably want to pass `topdown=False` to `os.walk`

Comment: `picpath = os.path.join(pic)` -> `picpath = os.path.join(root, pic)`

Comment: @mgilson nice idea unneeded here, but would probably be very useful if directories needed to be renamed.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre -- Yeah, I think you're right.  I didn't really look at the question too closely before I commented ...

Comment: @mgilson typical XY problem :) OPs have imagination to create vicious issues :)

Answer (score 1):

```
picpath = os.path.join(root, pic)
                    #  ^^^^^
```

looks like it should do the job.  Per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk),

> Note that the names in the lists contain no path components. To get a full path (which begins with top) to a file or directory in dirpath, do `os.path.join(dirpath, name).`

That is why you are getting a "No such file" error: you are asking for the filename in the current directory, which isn't `root` at the point the error happens.

Comment: also `if pic.endswith('.jpg'):` isn't safe. It would be better to use `if pic..lower().endswith('.jpg'):` or `fnmatch` module to avoid not seeing `IMG.JPG`

Comment: @Gshare If you are still having problems with the same code, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39710929/edit) to add the changes to the end (don't replace what's already there).  If this problem is solved and now you have a different problem, please ask a new question!

Comment: the `lower()` in the destination will kill it on case-sensitive filesystem: python will be unable to rename the whole dir structure to lowercase!!

Comment: Thanks all - appreciated I used `picpath = os.path.join(root, pic)` and I can see if I print at that level it prints the full path now which is great BUT it still fails with the same error.

Answer (score 1):

you have to append the directory name to your path or `os.rename` is unable to find the proper directory where to apply the rename.

That said, your conversion to lowercase complicates the task. lowercase must only be applied to the basename (that would work on Windows filesystem because case doesn't matter, but would fail on Linux if some directories of the path contain uppercase letters: fortunately, you cannot rename a whole dirtree with a single `rename` command)

And the match for `.jpg` extension should be done regardless of the casing, specially if you want to convert picture names to lowercase: extensions are likely to be in uppercase too (like all those DCIM cameras)

```
for root, subdirs, pics in os.walk(rootdir):
  for pic in pics:
    if pic.lower().endswith('.jpg'):  # more powerful: fnmatch.fnmatch(pic,"*.jpg")
        os.rename(os.path.join(root,pic), os.path.join(root,pic.replace(" ", "-").lower()))
```

Comment: Good catch!  That's a subtle one, for sure.

Comment: @cxw: I didn't want to post a concurrent answer, but there were still several potential issues, so it was becoming difficult to comment on each one. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Of course not!  Anyway, if you solve the OP's problem, you should get the rep you deserve for it :) .  I actually personally prefer answer edits or answer posts to comments (maybe one of the reasons I'll never be a moderator ;) ).

Comment: Thanks very much to you all.....Jean-Francois, your latest fixed it perfectly....thanks again.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre 100% C= (you are the first to recognize and comment on it;) )!  Offtopic comment - I saw Amigaaaaah stuff on your Web page - if you don't know the demoscene you should check it out.  E.g., [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpK3Kp7-0zU) ([details](https://www.pouet.net/prod.php?which=16337)).  All real-time rendering :)

Comment: @Gshare So if this code fixes your problem, hit the checkmark so the system will know.  You and Jean-Francois will both get reputation points when you do :) .

Comment: :) :) Maybe I'll catch you on pouet sometime.  Or post any comment at [devwrench.com](http://www.devwrench.com) <blatant plug> ;)  OK - time to get back to work :) o/

Comment: @cwx no problem. SO takes me away from amiga right now, but I'm not lost for the cause. Time to cleanup my OT comments...